# Inverse of grep's A

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I know that I can print the "next" line of a match with `grep`, with `-A1`, but what about the inverse of that? I mean, "hide the next line after a filter match".

Example:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

`cat letters.txt | grep -A1 -v "c"` <-- hide "c" and "d"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with `sed` like

```
sed -ne '/c/{n;d;}; p' letters.txt
```

This will read the file `letters.txt`.  Any line that does not match a `c` will be printed, if a `c` is matched, do not print that, and also go to the next line and delete that from the output

With GNU sed to make it easier to get N lines it can be done like

```
sed -ne '/c/,+1d; p;' letters.txt
```

and you can change the `1` to whatever number you like.  Also, you could add the `-i` flag to `sed` to make it modify the file in place if you wanted to do that

Comment: This is actually matching `d` instead of "the next line". I don't know the content of the line after `c`, so this  is not really helpful.

Comment: No, it isn't. The `d` is the `sed` command to delete the following line, and not a regex at all.

Comment: @alexandernst Why do you think it's matching d?  the `d` in the sed command is the command to delete the line

Comment: @EricRenouf Oh, sorry, I got confused by the `d`.

Comment: @alexandernst yeah, I guess it was a pretty confusing coincidence if one doesn't know that about sed

Comment: @mklement0 good point, I put a version in that will go to N easily too

Comment: Cool, didn't know about the `+N` address form. I know this question is tagged `linux`, bout it would still be helpful to note in your answer that `+N` is a _GNU_ Sed extension.
You could simplify to `sed '/c/,+1d' letters.txt`.
If you don't want to change the 1st command to the simpler `sed '/c/{N;d;}'  letters.txt` (note that `N` here is a Sed function that appends the next line to the current one), please add a `;` before `}` to make the command _portable_ (to make it work on BSD and OSX platforms too).

Answer (score 4):

`grep` by itself doesn't (usually) offer this functionality, but it's easy enough with Awk or `sed`.

```
awk '/c/ { skip=1; next }
    skip { skip=0; next } 1' letters.txt
```

Comment: What about N number of lines after 'c'?

Comment: Easy enough with a minor modification, but I would urge you to look at the proposed duplicate instead, since it already covers all of this, and much more.

Answer (score 2):

This answer looks at *general* solutions with *variable* skip count.

---

**If you have *GNU* `sed`, [Eric Renouf's elegant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30355598/45375) is the simplest solution.**

It can be slightly simplified to `sed '/c/,+1d'`, or, generalized:

```
regex='c' count=2
sed "/${regex}/,+${count}d" letters.txt  # skips c, d, e
```

The `+<n>` form of a context address to match the `<n>`-th line *from the start of the range* (and thus the start of the range *through* the following `<n>` lines) is a GNU `sed` extension.

Note that `$count` **+1** lines are skipped: the line matching the regex + `$count` lines *after*.

---

**For portability** and **for more flexibility in general** (such as not skipping the matching line itself), use **a generalized version of [tripleee's helpful `awk` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30355580/45375)**:

```
awk -v regex='c' -v count=2 \
  '$0 ~ regex { skip=count; next } --skip >= 0 { next } 1' letters.txt # skips c, d, e
```

Note that `$count` **+1** lines are skipped: the line matching the regex + `$count` lines *after*.

- `-v regex='c' -v count=2` defines `awk` variables with the specified values.
- `$0 ~ regex` matches the line of interest

  - `{ skip=count; next }` initializes the skip count and proceeds to the next line, effectively skipping the matching line; in the 2nd solution, the `print` before `next` ensures that it is *not* skipped.
  - `--skip >= 0` decrements the skip count and takes action if it is (still) >= 0, implying that the line at hand should be skipped.
  - `{ next }` proceeds to the next line, effectively skipping the current line
- `1` is a commonly used shorthand for `{ print }`; that is, the current line is simply printed

  - Only non-matching and non-skipped lines reach this command.
  - <sup>The reason that `1` is equivalent to `{ print }` is that `1` is interpreted as a Boolean pattern that by definition always evaluates to true, which means that its associated action (block) is unconditionally executed. Since there is *no* associated action in this case, `awk` defaults to *printing* the line.</sup>

As a POSIX-compliant **shell function**:

```
# SYNOPSIS
#   matchAndSkip regex skipCount [file]
matchAndSkip() {
  awk -v regex="$1" -v count="$2" \
    '$0 ~ regex { skip=count; next } --skip >= 0 { next } 1' "${3-/dev/stdin}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk you can also do:

```
awk -v s='c' '$0 ~ s {getline;next} 1' letters.txt
a
b
e
```

Comment: What about N number of lines after 'c'?

Comment: @alexandernst: You can use: `awk -v s='c' -v n=3 '$0 ~ s{for(i=1; i<=n; i++) getline;next} 1' file`